# Construct a DFA for language: All strings start with 1, must contain 11 as substring and if 0 comes it must be odd

Tags: finite-automata

I have to construct a DFA for a language:

1. All strings start with 1,
2. Must contain 11 as a substring
3. if 0 comes it must be odd.

Example:

```
11     // Valid. 
1011   // Valid.
1000011 //Valid.

1 //Invalid.
10 //Invalid.
1010   // Invalid.
100001 //Invalid.
```

I tried a lot but didn't succeed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: That was not homework.

Answer (score 1):

This is the DFA for your question.

It satisfies all the 3 conditions:

1. All strings start with 1
2. Must contain 11 as a substring
3. If 0 comes it must be odd.

[image: DFA]

Comment: If it fails at any string, please let me know.